# Wrong dates in the index plotly with a second graph I did not ask for

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot some graphs with plotly and, after several times having the wrong graph, i backed to the basics and tried to plot an example from the plotly web, but the same error appears:
My dates are not dates, but an extremely high number (10^18 order) and I get a second small graph that noone asked for.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas_datareader as web
from datetime import datetime
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

yf.pdr_override()

df = web.DataReader("aapl", 'robinhood').reset_index()

trace = go.Candlestick(x=df.Date,
                       open=df.Open,
                       high=df.High,
                       low=df.Low,
                       close=df.Close)
data = [trace]
py.plot(data, filename='simple_candlestick')
```

I just changed the source (morningstar is down) and used the offline version instead of the live program, but the error still appeared if I used the web anyways, so It does not matter.

EDIT:
After a previous edit, the images are no longer appearing in the post, sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Try after changing `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: That wont work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix the date problem inserting the index with dates in an array and using that array as the x.
Also, I figured out that the second small graph only appears with the go.Candlestick representation (since it does not appear with figure_factory or go.Scatter hehe).
Thanks :)